# how to pass parameter that I get from one Stored Procedure to another Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to execute stored procedure that his ID will be the execute of another stored procedure. how can I do this?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spABC]       
       @ID INT
      ,@TypeString nvarchar(50)

AS 
BEGIN 
    --exec SECOND_SP

    INSERT INTO dbo.abc (Id, TypeString)  
    VALUES (@"result from the second sp.", @TypeString)
END
```

Comment: Do you want to pass the `@ID INT` to `SECOND_SP`, or do you want to use the return value of the `SECOND_SP` in some way?

Comment: @moshe . . . You would use an `out` parameter to get the value from the second stored procedure.  Or, if you can, rewrite it as a stored function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gordon wrote in the comments, You could have an `output` parameter on the second stored procedure. another option would be to use [rahul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567435/rahul)'s [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30694644/3094533) (if the second stored procedure simply returns a scalar value)

here is a quick example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Second_SP
(
    @InParam varchar(10),
    @OutParam int OUTPUT -- note the OUTPUT directive
)
AS

-- do stored procedure stuff here

-- set a value to the output parameter:
SET @OutParam = 1234
GO
```

in the first stored procedure you should use the `output` directive when executing the second procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spABC]       
       @ID INT
      ,@TypeString nvarchar(50)

AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @InParam varchar(10), 
            @OutParam int

    -- set parameters values before executing...

    exec SECOND_SP @InParam, @OutParam OUTPUT -- note the output directive

    INSERT INTO dbo.abc (Id, TypeString)  
    VALUES (@OutParam, @TypeString)
END
```

Comment: Regarding "another option would be to use rahul's example (if the second stored procedure simply returns a scalar value)": No, that is not exactly correct. A stored procedure return value can only be `INT`. This case is not necessarily for an `INT`, and even if it is, that is not how return values (from stored procedures) should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why all the down votes on the question.  English may be a little weak, but stored procedure parameters are arcane.

You must define the procedure AND the EXEC as passing the parameter and expecting OUTPUT.   Stored procedure can include a RETURN, but I am pretty sure that value is always an INTEGER, and OP wants a string.

For example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
GO 
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SECOND_SP (@ID INT, @Type VARCHAR(9) OUTPUT)
AS 
--  totally arbitrary, pretend logic for second sp for illustrative purposes
SET @Type = CASE WHEN @ID > 90000 THEN 'ADMIN' 
                 WHEN @ID > 9000 THEN     'MANAGER' ELSE 'USER' END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spABC]       
   @ID INT
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @TypeString VARCHAR(9)
 exec SECOND_SP @ID, @Type = @TypeString OUTPUT

SELECT @ID, @TypeString 
--  INSERT INTO dbo.abc (Id, TypeString)   VALUES (@"result from the second sp.", @TypeString)
END    
GO
  --TEST IT .....
EXEC [dbo].[spABC]    1111
EXEC [dbo].[spABC]    9123
EXEC [dbo].[spABC]    99543

ROLLBACK 

--- RESULTS: 
1111        USER
----------- ---------
9123        MANAGER
----------- ---------
99543       ADMIN
```

Comment: Yes, a return value can only ever be `INT`. And as I have mentioned on the other answers here, that is not a good use of a stored procedure return value anyway. The `OUTPUT` param is 1 of 2 ways to go, so +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot update `SECOND_SP` to return the value as an `OUTPUT` parameter, and that stored procedure returns a single row, you can insert that into a Temporary Table (i.e. `#Table`) or a Table Variable (i.e. `@Table`) and then get the value from that table. Something along the lines of:

```sql
DECLARE @TempProcResult TABLE (ID INT, OtherField VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @TempProcResult (ID, OtherField)
  EXEC SECOND_SP @ID;

INSERT INTO dbo.abc (Id, TypeString)
  SELECT tmp.ID, @TypeString
  FROM   @TempProcResult tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Per your post, Considering that your second procedure `SECOND_SP` needs the `@ID` parameter and you want to have the return value of second procedure to the `INSERT` statement. you can do that like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spABC]       
       @ID INT
      ,@TypeString nvarchar(50)

AS 
BEGIN 

    declare @var int;
    exec @var = SECOND_SP @ID;

    INSERT INTO dbo.abc (Id, TypeString)  
    VALUES (@var, @TypeString)
END
```

**EDIT:**

Per comment from @srutzky. Try the below and see if works or not

```
create procedure test
as
begin
return 1009;
end

declare @var int;
exec @var = test;
select @var;
```

Comment: A few notes: **1)** This only works with `INT` as that is the only datatype of a stored proc `RETURN` value, **2)** it is not clear what the OP wants the datatype to be (you are interpreting from the column name "id" and Stan is interpreting from the string portion of the variable name in the question), and **3)** a stored proc return value should be used to return a status pertaining to the operation of the procedure, not actual information from the procedure. So while this _might_ work here and in some other cases, it is generally not a good practice.